# Proof of the time to get to the bottom of the brachistochrone curve (cycloid)

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In the exercise, we have to prove that the time to get to the lowest part of this curve is $\pi \sqrt{\frac{a}{g}}$ no matter the initial point (which I am considering as $\theta = \alpha$).

[image: cycloid]

I have done the following

$y = a(\theta - sin(\theta))$

$x = a(1 - cos(\theta))$

$t = \int \frac{ds}{v}$

$v = \sqrt{2g(x - x_0)}$

$x_0 = a(1 - cos(\alpha))$

$v = \sqrt{2ga(cos(\alpha) - cos(\theta)}$

$t = \int_{\theta = \alpha}^{\theta = \pi} \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{g}} \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - cos(\theta)}}{\sqrt{cos(\alpha) - cos(\theta)}} d\theta$

Currently, I am in trouble to evaluate this integral. But I guess I am not solving the entire exercise the right way. Any hint?

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem and came here looking for an answer!

Comment: Found an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870119/proving-the-tautochrone-property